# How to retrieve the DS-160 application of a family member from the US embassy website?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, spouses, applications

After completing my DS-160, I clicked on application for a family member on the "Thank you" page. New application started and then I went on to the "Getting Started" page just to review. It exited the application.

Now that I try to retrieve that application, it asks for application id, 5 letters of surname, and birth year in addition to the secret question. I have the Application ID and the secret question, but I haven't yet provided surname and birth year of my spouse. I tried to put my details instead: it says 'surnames does not match' and 'year of birth does not match'. How do I retrieve the application?

Answer (score 3):

Simply start a new application. There's no harm in having two "draft" applications at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a new application, your initial DS-160 will be deleted from the system after 30 days. There is no harm in filling a new DS-160. Also make sure to save data every now and then as DS-160 logs you out after some time of inactivity.